# Php MySQL Bind with "AS" not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple query that works fine in MySQL Workbench. I have narrowed it down to the "AS distance" portion of the code. Am I missing something about the binding process with using "AS" mapping the result to a variable?

```
// prepare
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, SQRT(POW(69.1 * (latitude - ?), 2) + POW(69.1 * (? - longitude) * COS(latitude / 57.3), 2)) AS distance FROM discussion_table WHERE is_featured = 0 AND is_draft = 0 AND is_archived = 0 AND is_bout = 0 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 50")){
        // set
        $stmt->bind_param("ssi", $latitude_in, $longitude_in, $created_time);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result($discussion_id, $discussion_distance);

        // cycle
        while($stmt->fetch()){
            // create
            $discussion_json = $discussion_class->getDiscussion($discussion_id, $user_id);
            $discussion_json['distance'] = $discussion_distance;

            // add
            array_push($results_array, $discussion_json);
        }

        // close
        $stmt->close();
    }
```

Comment: So, what happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: AS really shouldn't cause a problem. What is `$created_time` being bound to?

Comment: @Don'tPanic looks like you were right, there *is* an extra binding value.

Comment: @ishegg well, sort of. Somehow I didn't see _any_ of them when I first looked at it. I almost hated to ask about it again, ha

Comment: Not sure if it has to do with it, but the first two parameters are strings, yet you are performing calculations with them.

Comment: @Ivan, might be that but not likely. MySQL should just cast to the type it deems appropriate for the request. One should still obviously use the correct data type though. See [point 3) in this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#102917)

Comment: It was the extra binding param. I previously had a date greater than the current time and I removed it when adding the distance to my query. But I left the param. Good catch. Thank you all!!!